# How to fit a continuous empirical variable to a theoretical distribution?

Tags: r, distributions

Let's suppose I have a set of measurements on a continuous variable which follows a power law distribution, and I’m interested in deriving the exponent of such a distribution.

So far I've used the binning method, so I was dividing the interval in n bins, plotting the number of observation for each bin in log-log scale and fitting a regression line trough the data. However this way of estimating the exponent is not enough accurate.

Now I’d like to move on and use the maximum likelihood method. But I’m a bit confused, maybe because I keep referring to the binning method. I know how to write the function of the expected theoretical distribution but I can’t visualize how to derive the empirical distribution.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the `fitdistrplus` package, which has better support for maximum likelihood estimation. Read the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/vignettes/intro2fitdistrplus.pdf) for more details on how to go about estimating any distribution. Here is an example using a weibull distribution.

```
# LOAD LIBRARIES 
library(fitdistrplus);
library(ggplot2);

# GENERATE DUMMY DATA 
x1 = rweibull(100, shape = 0.5, scale = 1); 

# ESTIMATE WEIBULL DISTRIBUTION
f1 = fitdist(x1, 'weibull', method = 'mle');

# PLOT HISTOGRAM AND DENSITIES
p0 = qplot(x1[x1 > 0.1], geom = 'blank') +
  geom_line(aes(y = ..density.., colour = 'Empirical'), stat = 'density') +  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), fill = 'gray90', colour = 'gray40') +
  geom_line(stat = 'function', fun = dweibull, 
     args = as.list(f1$estimate), aes(colour = 'Weibull')) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Density', values = c('red', 'blue')) + 
  opts(legend.position = c(0.85, 0.85))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For fitting continuous distributions (like exponential) try to use `fitdistr()` from package MASS (see `?fitdistr` or the [Ricci's paper](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) as DWin pointed out). It uses maximum likelihood parameter estimation.

You should probably ask at stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is true that most statistical software package come with function implementing the stuff for you however, I always find it useful to understand how the black box works.

So in the case of the MLE for the power law (easy to derive), the best $\alpha$ estimate is

$\hat \alpha = 1+ n\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\ln{x_i/x_{min}}\right)^{-1}$ where $x_{min}$ is the smallest observation you have and $n$ the number of observations.

You can then plot

$y=\frac{1-\hat\alpha}{x_{min}}\left(\frac{x}{x_{min}}\right)^{-\hat\alpha}$